# Nanosecond Time in Java Without Using java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, time, garbage-collection, precision

I have the need for extremely precise and accurate time with as few garbage collections (GCs) as possible, ideally 1 per day. `System.currentTimeMillis()` is not precise enough, `System.nanoTime()` isn't an accurate source of time. The only thing that will give me what I want is `java.util.Date.getTime()` but it's not a static method so I have to create a new `Date` object every time I need precise and accurate time which causes GC to be triggered more often.

Does anyone know how the `Date` class gets accurate and precise time? I'm hoping to take Date's method and tailor it to minimize object creation. To summarize my problem, see the following:

```
long nanosSinceEpoch;
nanosSinceEpoch = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Not precise
nanosSinceEpoch = System.nanoTime();          // Not accurate
nanosSinceEpoch = new Date().getTime();       // Too many objects
```

### EDIT:

I'm not sure why I thought `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `new Date().getTime()` were different but it turns out they are the same. But that didn't fix my problem sadly.

Also, `getNano()` from `java.time.Instant` appears to only have millisecond resolution.

Comment: I didnt find any difference between the time returned by 1st and 3rd option. For instance, I tried to execute both the statements and got below value: 1522333417157 . Am I missing anything?

Comment: Well, the constructor of `Date` uses `System#currentTimeMillis`.

Comment: 1) Nowadays, you should use [`Instant.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now()) instead of `new Date()` (although there are more object creations involved). 2) "I have to create a new [...] object [...] which causes GC to be triggered more often." => Any proof of that? If you simply create a new object, and its reference does not _escape_ the method, the object is most likely created on the stack and not on the heap. See the article on [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis). The GC then has no work to do!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose - You have just change my life. Thank you!

Comment: After doing some testing. I've found that `Instant.now().getNano()` isn't any more precise than `(System.currentTimeMillis() % 1_000) * 1_000_000` i.e. it zero-pads the micro and nano seond digits. I'm using openJDK8 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @SomeGuy You assume conventional computer hardware clocks can track time to nanosecond precision. Your assumption is incorrect, as of 2018. Perhaps in future hardware, but not today’s hardware.

Comment: @BasilBourque RDTSC gets you within a precision of a few dozen nanoseconds.

Comment: @the8472 The [Wikipedia article on Time Stamp Counter (TSC) and RDTSC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) makes it sound like that feature is *not* practical/reliable for time-keeping on modern hardware.

Comment: @BasilBourque it is practical and reliable on many but not all *modern* systems. The "but not all" part mostly means it requires some probing by the OS at boot time. It is used under the hood by various time sources if possible.

Comment: @the8472 Unless I have misunderstood, according to the Wikipedia article that facility is not to be relied upon for accurate time-keeping on (a) any machine with multiple CPUs, (b) any multi-core machine, (c) any hyper-threaded machine, (d) any machine with out-of-order execution, nor (e) any machine running MS Windows OS. What modern system does that leave remaining?

Comment: You have indeed misunderstood, *modern* processors have fixed most of the issues that were present on *older* processors. But elaborating would not be appropriate for comments.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose “*the object is most likely created on the stack*”—that’s a tenacious wrong explanation of what will happen. A JVM like HotSpot *never* allocates objects on the stack. What will happen, is dissolving the object’s fields into variables, most likely getting replaced by whatever data source actually determined their value (though mutable variables may even spawn new variables), just like the optimizer treats local variables. Or, in other words, the object will not get allocated at all.

Answer (score 6):

## `Instant.now`

Java 9 brought a fresh implementation of `Clock` able to capture the current moment in a precision finer than the [milliseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) capability of Java 8’s `Clock`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Let me be clear: The `Instant` class in *all* versions of Java is able to *hold* a value in [nanoseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). But *capturing the current moment* is limited to milliseconds in Version 8 specifically.

You should research the capabilities of the hardware clock of your current computer equipment. I believe you will find that current conventional hardware is not capable of accuracy in tracking time to the nanosecond.

In using Oracle JDK 9.0.4 on macOS Sierra, I am seeing current moment captured in [microseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond), six digits of decimal fractional second.

> System.nanoTime() isn't an accurate source of time

No, accuracy is not the issue. The issue there is that [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) is **designed to track *elapsed* time**, not the current date-time. This feature simply tracks a count of nanoseconds since an arbitrary undocumented starting point.

And again, as noted above, we are not talking about incrementing by single nanoseconds as current conventional computer hardware is not capable.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

> System.nanoTime() isn't an accurate source of time

This is not quite true. Its accuracy is [highly system-dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33718924/1362755). If you have control over your hardware and OS you can in principle construct a high precision clock from it even on older java versions.

Since [JDK-8068730](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730) has been implemented the newer time APIs shield you from those complexities by deferring to the most accurate OS clock available which in turn will do the necessary hardware feature detection to figure out whether the TSCs are reliable enough to be used as a time source.